# Unique by column 1, while prioritizing rows with non empty column 2

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm uniquing a CSV full of rows with duplicate data based on column 1 with the following command:

```
sort -u -t, -k1,1 file
```

I want to modify this to save the rows where column 2 isn't empty as the first choice, discarding the rows where column 2 is empty if there is a better choice available, while still preserving the uniqued rows where all duplicated data rows have a blank column 2 thus making all choices for that row equal.

**Example data:**

- hello@stackoverflow.com, david, lynch
- hello@stackoverflow.com, , lynch
- hello@stackoverflow.com, ,
- hey@stackoverflow.com, ,
- hey@stackoverflow.com, ,

row 1 is the desired preserved output of all the choices, but we still want to preserve 1 version of row 4/5 since they're equivalent

Comment: Please provide sample input and the desired output based on it.

Comment: What type is `-k1`? Is it a number? `-n` would help in that case. Include some input and the expected output in your question.

Comment: @shawn example added

Comment: @TedLyngmo example data added

Comment: @Underflow, please do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS as it's not clear as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

something like this will work, but there is no control on which row to pick (this will take the latest) if there are more than one record with not null second field.

```
$ awk -F, '!($1 in a) || $2!="" {a[$1]=$0} 
            END {for(k in a) print a[k]}' file

hello@stackoverflow.com, david,lynch
hey@stackoverflow.com,,
```

Comment: thanks this seems to work!